# Display unicode string in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a char* string like that

[image]

and I expect it displays as following:

> Nguyễn Đức Hoàng Hỏi Ngã Nặng

It seems an Unicode string, doesn't it? How can I display in my List control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a UTF-8 encoded string. To display it in a Unicode control you must first convert it to UTF-16 which is the native encoding used on Windows. You perform that conversion using, for example, [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
char subjectTemp[255];
WCHAR subjectWTemp[255];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, subjectTemp, -1, subjectWTemp, 255);
```